# How can I check if the phone number already exists in the mongo db?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

What im trying to do is to push new clients phone number and fullName into selectedClients field in the database.
The code works well, but how can make a condition to check if the number exists(and if exist, to not add that number in the selectedClients field).

controller/auth.js

```
const { fullName, phone, userPhone } = req.body;
const userPhone1 = req.body[0].userPhone;

for (const client in req.body) {
    let clients = [];
    const fullName = req.body[client].fullName;
    const phone = req.body[client].phone; // this number needs to be checked if it exists
    let sendClients;

    clients = await User.findOne({ phone });
    
    if (clients ) {
      duplicateClients.push({fullName: clients.fullName, phone: clients.phone})

    } 
 
// here I push the clients in the selectedClients field
  if(duplicateTrustees){
    sendTrustee = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
      {phone : userPhone1},
      {$push: {selectedClients: duplicateClients}},
      {new: true}
    )
  }
 
  res.status(200, `The clients has been selected`).json({
    success: true
  });
});
```

How can I make a condition to check if phone number exists?

Comment: Do you ensure a fix format of the phone number?

Comment: Thats not the case, yet

Comment: When it will be difficult. The user may enter his phone number in many different formats.

Comment: All the numbers that exist in the database, are formated numbers. They get formated when the user register.